# Using dot product when finding shortest distance between a line and a point, not working

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

Question goes as follows:
Consider the points on a line; $A(1,3,-1)$ and $B(-1,4,-2)$. Find the point $Q$ on $L$ closest to the point $P(1,1,0)$.

My thinking:
Closest distance from $a$ to $b$ is always a straight line, $90$ degree angle.
Therefore:
$$
Q⋅P=0
$$

$$
L=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1\\
3\\
-1\\
\end{array}\right)
+
t
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-2\\
1\\
-1\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

$$
Q = 
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1-2t\\
3+t\\
-1-t\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

$$
(1-2t)\times(1)+(3+t)\times(1)+(-1-t)\times(0)=0
$$
$$
4-t=0
$$

$$t=4 
$$
and 
$$
Q=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-7\\
7\\
-5\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

But it is wrong, my answer tells me a different story and when I graph it is wrong.

Answer $Q(2,5/2,-1/2)$

Comment: You're supposed to find the point $Q$ such that the vectors $\vec{AQ}$ and $\vec{PQ}$ are perpendicular.

Comment: The dot product is an operation you can do on two *vectors*. If you are careful to distinguish between Vectors and Points, you could mechanically tell that Q \dot P doesn't have meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is incorrect.

You're supposed to find the point $Q$ such that the vectors $\vec{AQ}$ and $\vec{PQ}$ are perpendicular.

$\vec{AQ} = \vec{OQ} - \vec{OA} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
2t\\
-t\\
t\\
\end{array}\right)$

$\vec{PQ} = \vec{OQ} - \vec{OP} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
-2t\\
2+t\\
-1-t\\
\end{array}\right)$

Dot product the two and solve to get: $6t^2 + 3t = 0$.

Reject $t = 0$ (as this makes $Q$ coincident with $A$) to get $t = -\frac 12$, giving you the expected answer.

Comment: Is it because I can't use points when using the dot product? or is there a case when you would use something like QP=0? Thank you!

Comment: @user3170899 Try sketching a simple two-dimensional figure on paper. You should see why my method works and yours does not. The dot product applies to two vectors, not to points, but you can certainly use the dot product on coordinate vectors that go from the origin to those points. However, that is inapplicable to this problem, as a diagram will quickly show.

Answer (score 2):

If you pay attention to your graph, you will see that what you need is $(-2,1,-1)\cdot(P-Q)=0$. That is, 
\begin{align}
0&=-2(1-(1-2t))+(1-(3+t))-(-(-1-t))\\
&=-6t-3,\\
\end{align}
so $t=-1/2$, and your point in the line is 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1-2(-1/2)\\
3+(-1/2)\\
-1-(-1/2)\\
\end{array}\right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2\\
5/2\\
-1/2\\
\end{array}\right)
$$